# Why is my car wont start

Tags: electronic-control-module, battery-drain, buick, cranks-wont-run, regal

My mechanic changed my ecm and programmed it to my 2001 buick regal he programmed both sets of keys i have now all of a sudden car will crank but wont start also battery keep draining. Before he installed the ecm i had no lights such as battery and oil light with new ecm my battery like is on and oil light and he did a real time reading and now all cylinders are miss firing i dont know whats going on the reason for the ecm change was i took my car in because when i drive it started lagging i couldnt accelerate only go in low speeds it would gradually climb in spend so first they said it was crankshaft and 02 sensor we changed them then they said ecm we changed that car still drives the same

Comment: To summarize, when you took the car in, it would start and run, but wasn't picking up power? Now with a new ECM, crank and O2 sensors, it'll crank but won't run? Are there any codes being displayed by the vehicle? If so, what are they?